# Please explain this SQL statement in English!

Tags: sql

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.*,
       b.id AS user_id,
       a.id AS group_id 
FROM groups a,
     users b 
WHERE a.group_leader_id = b.id
```

Thank you.

Comment: Flint - I have reformatted the code in your question. This will hopefully help you to understand its structure better.

Comment: Ah, that did become clearer when it was reformatted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show all groups and only those users who are a leader of a group

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, 
b.id AS user_id, -- use an alias for users.id
a.id AS group_id -- use an alias for groups.id
FROM groups a, -- alias table groups as 'a'
  users b -- alias table users as 'b'
WHERE a.group_leader_id = b.id -- show only those users who are a leader of a group, and link them to that group
```

According to me, your query can be optimized to this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, b.id AS user_id, a.id AS group_id
FROM groups a 
  INNER JOIN users b ON a.group_leader_id = b.id
```

Comment: when you say 'optimized' do you mean explicit JOIN is faster than implied join?

Comment: It depends. If you are using SQL Server, the answer is "Yes". The reason for this is that the "ON" clause is executed before the "WHERE" block. For best practice use, i would strongly recommend the use of explicit joins over the "WHERE" clause.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plans created for both queries. You are likely to find that the optimizer has rewritten the "WHERE" join to the INNER JOIN syntax anyway. However, both alternatives are perfectly valid ANSI syntax. But I would also say, that it is better to use the explicite JOIN style.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, b.id //select all columns from a, b and id from table b with alias user_id
AS user_id, a.id     // id from table a with alias group_id
AS group_id 
FROM groups a, users b  //from tables groups and users with aliases a and b
WHERE a.group_leader_id = b.id  //where group_leader_id from groups = id from users.
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement is a join between two tables groups and users on the group leader foreign key of groups.

So I will state it this way:
Display the user information of the group leaders (with a redundant renaming of user_id and group_id).

Answer (score 1):

List all groups and their leaders.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    b.*, 
    b.id AS user_id, 
    a.id AS group_id 
FROM 
    groups a
INNER JOIN 
    users b 
ON 
    a.group_leader_id = b.id
```

Comment: Why have you converted it into an `OUTER` join? The statement in the Q is an inner JOIN.

Comment: @Martin You are right, I made a mistake. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means pick out Group Leaders(doesn't say what details) from 2 tables where B has the list of Group Leaders, and A has the user's details.

Answer (score 0):

Give me all columns from group + all columns from users + rename b.id as user_id + rename a.id as group_id from all rows in groups where there is a match from groups to users.